# Why is it good to borrow money to buy a house?

Tags: mortgage, debt, home-ownership

In most cases of purchases the general advice is to save the money and then make the purchase.  Paying cash for a car is recommended over paying credit for example.  For a house, getting a mortgage is recommended.

Is this because a house is so expensive, saving is not practical?  Is it because the house is expected to appreciate in value?  Then isn't a mortgage really just an option to own a property that you buy with borrowed money and you're betting that the house's price will increase?

Comment: Once you have bought a house, you don't have to pay rent anymore. For most other goods the alternative to buying is abstinence, not renting them.

Comment: This question is a companion question to this one: [Is a car loan bad debt?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/47621/10997)

Comment: leverage. thats why

Comment: People borrow to buy houses because they either don't want to wait until they have saved the full value of a house, or because they have that but not enough more to reasonably safely live on after buying a house for cash ("house rich, cash poor" is a rather illiquid position to be in), or because they believe they can get enough gains from their investments to more than cover the cost of the loan, or some combination of these.

Comment: @CodesInChaos but you **do** have to pay property tax and maintain it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In most cases of purchases the general advice is to save the money and
>   then make the purchase. Paying cash for a car is recommended over
>   paying credit for example. For a house, getting a mortgage is
>   recommended.

Says who? These rules of thumb hide the actual equations behind them; they should be understood as heuristics, not as the word of god.

**The Basics**

The basic idea is, if you pay for something upfront, you pay some fixed cost, call it *X*, where as with a loan you need to pay interest payments on *X*, say *%I*, as well as at least fixed payments *P* at timeframe *T*, resulting in some long term payment *IX*.

**Your Assumption**

To some, this obviously means upfront payments are better than interest payments, as by the time the loan is paid off, you will have paid more than *X*. This is a good rule of thumb (like Newtonian's equations) at low *X*, high *%I*, and moderate *T*, because all of that serves to make the end result *IX* > *X*.

**Counter Examples**

Are there circumstances where the opposite is true? Here's a simple but contrived one: you don't pay the full timeframe. Suppose you die, declare bankruptcy, move to another country, or any other event that reduces *T* in such a way that *XI* is less than *X*. This actually is a big concern for older debtors or those who contract terminal illnesses, as you can't squeeze those payments out of the dead. This is basically manipulating the whole concept.

Let's try a less contrived example: suppose you can get a return higher than *%I*. I can currently get a loan at around %3 due to good credit, but index funds in the long run tend to pay %4-%5. Taking a loan and investing it may pay off, and would be better than waiting to have the money, even in some less than ideal markets. This is basically manipulating *T* to deal with *IX*.

Even less contrived and very real world, suppose you know your cash flow will increase soon; a promotion, an inheritance, a good market return. It may be better to take the loan now, enjoy whatever product you get until that cash flows in, then pay it all off at once; the enjoyment of the product will make the slight additional interest worth it. This isn't so much manipulating any part of the equation, it's just you have different goals than the loan.

**Home Loan Analysis**

For long term mortgages, *X* is high, usually higher than a few years pay; it would be a large burden to save that money for most people.

*%I* is also typically fairly low; *P* is directly related to *%I*, and the bank can't afford to raise payments too much, or people will rent instead, meaning *P* needs to be affordable. This does not apply in very expensive areas, which is why cities are often mostly renters.

*T* is also extremely long; usually mortgages are for 15 or 30 years, though 10 year options are available. Even with these shorter terms, it's basically the longest term loan a human will ever take. This long term means there is plenty of time for the market to have a fluctuation and raise the investments current price above the remainder of the loan and interest accrued, allowing you to sell at a profit.

As well, consider the opportunity cost; while saving money for a home, *you still need a place to live*. This additional cost is comparable to mortgage payments, meaning *X* has a hidden constant; the cost of renting. Often *X + R* > *IX*, making taking a loan a better choice than saving up.

**Conclusion**

"The general advice" is a good heuristic for most common human payments; we have relatively long life spans compared to most common payments, and the opportunity cost of not having most goods is relatively low.

However, certain things have a high opportunity cost; if you can't talk to HR, you can't apply for jobs (phone), if you can't get to work, you can't eat (car), and if you have no where to live, it's hard to keep a job (house). For things with high opportunity costs, the interest payments are more than worth it.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but I really like that you restrict this statement by species: "the longest term loan a human will ever take."

Comment: "Taking a loan and investing it may pay off, and would be better than waiting to have the money, even in some less than ideal markets" But, if you take out a loan to pay for a house and then invest it instead, that means you don't have any money to buy the house with, correct? Or by "investing" did you mean "investing in buying a house"?

Comment: @Dave Galapagos tortoises can take out mortgages lasting up to 200 years!

Answer (score 12):

First, who is saying that it is a better option? In general it is best to pay cash for things when you can. I think the reality is that for most people owning a house would be very difficult without some sort of financing.

That said, one argument for financing a house these days even if you could afford to pay cash is that the interest rates are very low. For a 30-year fixed loan you can borrow money under 4.5% APR with decent credit. If you are willing to accept even a little risk you could almost certainly invest that same money and get a return higher than 4.5%. With the US mortgage interest tax deduction the numbers are even more favorable for financing.

Those rates look even more attractive when you consider you are paying for the house with today's dollars and paying back the loan with dollars from up to 30 years in the future, which will be worth much less.

Comment: To clarify, yes you're right no one is saying that a mortgage is better than paying cash.  My point is that in the discussion of home buying that a mortgage will be taken is generally assumed.  My real question is better phrased as "If buying on credit is good for a house because it is expected to appreciate, then why don't financial professionals encourage people to buy other assets that are expected to appreciate using credit?  Why don't financial planners suggest people buy stocks on margin?".  Really besides the interest rate, these scenarios are the same thing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "expected to appreciate". Taking a low-rate mortgage when you don't absolutely have to  can be a relatively low-risk opportunity to do some leveraged investing, as noted in John's answer... but the house you are living in is ___housing___, not investment; trying to consider it both at once leads to things like the recent foreclosure storm.

Comment: Interesting opinion.  You're right that it really depends on how you see the purchase.  If you are really buying a house to live in and nothing more, then yes it's not an investment.  I do think that "expected to appreciate" has very much to do with it because people with underwater mortgages aren't just happily continuing to pay every month and patting themselves on that back that even though their house is worth 30% of what they paid, they sure are glad it's "not an investment".

Comment: If you understand that it isn't an investment, being under water is absolutely irrelevant until/unless you have to sell it. (Well, almost. It may force you to pay for PMI.) And if you understand that it isn't an investment, you will be tremendously less likely to overbuy/overpay under the assumption that you are certain to sell it for a profit; that assumption  is the major cause of underwater situations.

Comment: "which will be worth much less" -- careful now. The low rate of interest you're paying is strongly dependent on the current low rate of inflation. So the thing that causes "dollars in 30 years will be worth much less" to be true, is also *liable* to cause "the interest rates are very low" to become less true. Even 1% inflation compounded over 30 years is a good chunk off the real value of the loan, but the current US CPI is 0.2%. In general unless you make a good decision on a fixed rate, any benefit you get from inflation is something you've already paid for in the interest rate.

Comment: @oceanus `"If buying on credit is good for a house because it is expected to appreciate, then why don't financial professionals encourage people to buy other assets that are expected to appreciate using credit? Why don't financial planners suggest people buy stocks on margin?"` A mortgage is a collateralized loan. Stocks and other investments for the most part are not. By being collateralized you take out a lot of the risk involved in lending. With stocks your potential risk is the value of the stock going to 0 and therefor you lose everything.  Houses this is not possible (for the most part).

Comment: @Ross Of course margin loans are collateralized!  That's why there's the possibility of a margin call (and selling the collateral; the stocks) before the stock price hits zero.

Comment: I never said they weren't.  That isn't exactly the point I was trying to make though.  Instead was trying to show that houses are hard assets that usually do not have a 0 value to reach whereas stocks can.  This is why people don't promote using margin and investing using credit.  It's all about that risk ;)

Comment: @Ross Houses also have risk of going to zero.  If your house gets blown away by a hurricane, it's worth zero.  As I understand what you're saying houses are valuable because it's unlikely they'll go to zero and they are hard assets.  Would it be prudent then to buy REIT equities on credit?  It would be more diversified than putting all your money into one house.

Comment: Unless you own the house 100% outright you have to carry insurance I believe - negating the risk of the underlying asset being worth 0. But as for REIT's I'm not sure.  They are their own specialized vehicles and I haven't looked into them too much (I only have one in my portfolio). I would imagine they could go to 0 as well as bondholders would get paid before stock holders in the REIT's but not sure.  Houses still are safer I believe than even REIT's but not as diversified.  Overall it comes down to how much risk the lender is willing to accept in loaning you the money. Hence hedge funds.

Comment: And if your house blows away, you still own the land, which in many places is the larger part of the value.

Answer (score 2):

First, as others have commented, the idea that getting a mortgage to buy a house is *always* a good idea is false.  It depends on a number of factors including the current interest rate, what you think the future interest rate will do over the life of your mortgage, the relative cost of renting vs. buying, and how long you would stay in the house that you bought.

To the extent that a mortgage for a house is more often recommended than buying other goods on credit, it is for these reasons:

1. In the US at least, there is a tax deduction for mortgage interest but not 
   for other types of interest paid. This means that to some extent you're choosing between paying money to the IRS or to the bank. It's a deduction not a credit, so this is not a $1-for-$1 trade, but in a lot of cases it can help tip the balance toward taking the loan.
2. Over recent history especially, the mortgage interest rate has been low. Between inflation, which will tend to devalue the true cost of your mortgage, and the better-than-even odds that bank interest rates on savings will go up over the term of a 30 yr mortgage, you have some factors in your favor that you won't have on a higher-rate loan / credit card. (Inflation and increase saving interest rates won't help you enough on a credit card debt with 30% interest.)
3. As you note, there's some expectation / hope that a home will go up in value over time, so it has investment value.  Many other goods (but not all) that you might buy on credit will devalue.

Except for #1 above, you could and can find other situations where taking a loan makes more sense than buying in cash.  This more true if you have the resources and the skill to invest money at a rate that beats the interest rate you pay to the creditor.  The general advice not to try this rests in the fact that most people don't have the resources or the skill to actually make this pay off, especially on high-interest rate loans or over short time periods.

Comment: Another major financial reason for getting a mortgage to buy a home is when it is cheaper (including all relevant factors like maintenance, etc.) compared with renting. Depending on the market you're in, this may or may not be true, for a given length of time. I don't like the phrase "throwing away money on rent", but sometimes yes, rent payments due exceed the true cost of ownership even including the risk involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can explore the scenarios in which it is better to rent or to buy using this application:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BuyOrRentInvestmentReturnCalculator/

In the possibly unlikely scenario shown below, at the term of the mortgage (20 years) the tenant and the buyer have practically the same return on investment.  At this point the tenant's savings would be sufficient to buy a house equivalent to the buyer's, and this would be the advisable course of action (based on the figures alone).

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Actually the application specifically *does not* ignore the impact of saving money while renting.  As it says at the bottom, "The comparison assumes the use of equivalent capital" - so any difference between the buyer's mortgage and the tenant's rent is invested by the tenant at the deposit rate.  As for point A, the down payment, for simplicity the application models a 100% mortgage, so there is no down payment.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I have added a modeling details panel to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of saving first to buy a thing (anything) is that it costs you less - you aren't paying interest; depending on the economic climate (interest rate vs inflation) and the cost of the thing, deferring a purchase may allow you to afford something better when you can eventually buy it without borrowing.

The benefit of borrowing to buy a thing is that you get to enjoy it right away.

For many purchases like electronics, household appliances, and so forth, it shouldn't take all that long to save enough to pay in cash, so you're not significantly deferring the benefit of having it.

Cars, being more expensive, may take longer to save, and you may not be prepared (or able) to wait until you can pay cash for one, so borrowing allows you to gain the benefits of having one sooner, but it comes at a cost. If you can afford the financing cost, then it can make sense to borrow for a car, but you're always financially better off to save first and then buy.

Houses are generally the most expensive thing a person will buy, and for most people, it will require an impractically long time to save up enough to buy in cash. Since lenders generally view mortgages as low-risk investments, mortgages are typically the least expensive money you can get (lowest interest rates). This is what makes borrowing to buy a house a sensible option (assuming you can keep up the mortgage and all other associated expenses). Also, most properties appreciate in value over time; once you've bought in, you acquire the potential to benefit from appreciation when it comes time to sell (it's never guaranteed, but it is fairly certain in most cases); just about anything else you might buy will depreciate from the moment you buy it. Deferring a home purchase can make an eventual purchase more difficult (depending on market) because prices sometimes rise faster than average inflation.

It's been said that it's better to buy than rent, and the best time to buy was last year. These bits of wisdom are true in many cases, and used to favor the argument to borrow and buy now, but you always have to analyze the specifics of each individual case. What is your employment situation and income prospect over the next 5, 10, 20 years? What does the rental market look like in your area? How much will your desired house cost? How much have you saved so far toward a down payment? What will your cash flow look like after you buy (mortgage, taxes, utilities, maintenance, food, clothing, car and/or other transportation for yourself and any dependents, travel and entertainment)? Will you still have something left over for retirement savings, "rainy day" savings, discretionary spending? In general the question is not so much whether or not to borrow to buy a house, but whether or not to buy vs rent, and when to buy.